# How to get only year from facet.fields contains full date field in Solr JSON?

Tags: json, solr, lucene

How to get only year from facet.fields date field in Solr JSON ? Help me if you have solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will have to loop through the results and extract the year.

If extracting year from date is regular query to solr then it is preferable to index

year separately.

Hope this helps. In case you find a better solution do let me know.